# Where can I find the file swagger.json on my PC, referred to as "localhost"?

Tags: c#, docker, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

I'm developping a C# application, based on Swagger GUI.

When launching the application, my web browser goes to `http://localhost:5128/index.html`.

On that "web page", there is a reference to a "swagger.json" file, located in "`/swagger/v1/swagger.json`", which corresponds with this line of source code:

```
application.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Employee API V1");
    ...
```

However, both windows search and WSL search (`find /mnt/c/ -type f 2>/dev/null | grep -i "swagger.json"`) can't show me where to find that file.

I'm sure the file exists, because when I click on the URL, I get something like this:

[image]

Does anybody know where I can find the "swagger.json" file on my PC?

For your information: also the aforementioned directory "swagger" is not found on my PC.

Comment: It's generated on fly...

Comment: Folder paths in a URL don't need to correspond to actual paths to actual files in the server's filesystem. If they did, you wouldn't need to write custom code for a web server; the same web server could serve any website by just looking up the file at the specified path and sending it over the wire (this is called "static" web content).

Comment: This seems to be really a high-level, conceptual question about what web frameworks do and how the Internet works. It might be a better fit for https://serverfault.com, but I doubt the underlying question is well enough specified for that.

Comment: That said: if you want to understand how a specific web API works, conceptually, why not start by **reading its documentation**?

Comment: Why do you want the 'physical' location of the file? These looks like an [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @Silvermind: I would like to understand how the whole thing works.

Comment: @Selvin: Even if it is generated on the fly, it should be possible to find it: my application is running and showing the "swagger.json" file, but a search on my local PC does not yield any result.

Comment: @Dominique It does not exist on disk. Everytime you call that URL, the application sends you the contents from memory. The file is generated in memory on startup. Or maybe on the first call.

Comment: So the answer is: "*The file does not exist, neither does the whole "swagger/v1" directory structure. It's kept somewhere in memory by the web server and if asked, the content of the memory is dumped on screen, without that file actually being created.*", something like that? If this is correct, please add this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: By on fly I mean that it doesn't exists and its content is generated when client do request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that the .json file is not a physical file.  When Swagger starts it generates the json file and all associated web content based on the scan of your application controllers.  Therefore the swagger.json file is not on disk which is why you can't find it.